# Which size of fxml gui is right?

Tags: gluon-mobile

I have problems with gluon-mobile view sizing FXML, it use a different size I'm confused.

1. in the sample gluon-mobile it uses 350 x Height 600.
2. But in the scene builder File-> new Template it creates with 335 x Height 600
   both Template.

I need it for setup my Adobe XD for design the background image.

Can it be specified?

Answer (score 0):

Those sizes (350x600, 335x600) are set for reference, and to test on desktop, based on usual mobile formats, but the real size will be defined by the real device, and this can vary.

See for instance https://material.io/tools/devices/, where you can find several devices with 360x640 dp, but many other resolutions as well.

When you display your view with [Gluon Mobile](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.2/) on a real device, the scene will take the full available size.

If you want to retrieve this value, you can use the `DisplayService` (see [doc](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/DisplayService.html)):

```
    Services.get(DisplayService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
      // screen resolution of the device, in pixels
      Dimension2D resolution = service.getScreenResolution();
      System.out.printf("Screen resolution: %.0fx%.0f", resolution.getWidth(), resolution.getHeight());
      // default screen dimensions of a mobile device, in dp
      Dimension2D dimensions = service.getDefaultDimensions();
      System.out.printf("Screen dimensions: %.0fx%.0f", dimensions.getWidth(), dimensions.getHeight());
   });
```

If you want to use an image for the background, you can use css to set it to expand or adjust properly to the final size, as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) for `-fx-background-image`.

Answer (score 0):

ok, it's mean that I need export design img in all sizes like to

1. mipmap-hdpi
2. mipmap-ldpi
3. ...
4. mipmap-xxxhdpi
   ?